# Android Camera: "setParameters failed" With Supported Preview

Tags: java, android, camera

All the other SO posts on 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed`
Revolve around people setting something they shouldn't to the cameraParameters or trying to set it to a preview size it doesnt support.

However I am getting a list of supported camera sizes and setting it to a supported size.

```
    /**
     * Sets the cameraParams to new size based on display size
     */
    void setPreviewAndSurfaceHolderSize()
    {
        List<Camera.Size> sizesOfPreviews = _camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size size = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizesOfPreviews, displayWidth, displayHeight);
        printCameraPreviewSizes();
        _previewSize = size;
        int cameraPreviewWidth = size.width;
        int cameraPreviewHeight = size.height;

        System.out.println("Optimal camera preview size is " + cameraPreviewWidth + " x " + cameraPreviewHeight);
        Camera.Parameters params = _camera.getParameters();
        params.setPreviewSize(cameraPreviewWidth, cameraPreviewHeight);
}
```

My app lets the user change the size of the camera preview (from squares to rectangles). As such I need to switch the camera to fit the view. I get the closest supported preview size and use that. However when it uses 1280 x 720 it crashes even though its listed as one of the supported values.

Can you think why setParameters will fail on the camera when the only property being set is the preview size and that preview size is supported?

**Update**

After some testing its not crashing if I hard code in 1280 x 720 it does not crash but when switching from other dimensions to that it sometimes crashes (but I cant get it to reliably crash). I suspect there is some sort of race condition but I have no clue.

Comment: I remember faintly having that issue, too. If my memory is correct, I think you might have to stop the preview while changing certain parameters.

Comment: I definitely think its something up with that too. I've got a workaround, but I'd be curious if anyone knows a root cause. I don't think this camera safe even on one thread!

Comment: Camera is definitely not running on one thread. Camera is actually running out of your process, and mediaserver uses `bind` to establish communication between the camera and your app. Therefore, you should not switch resolution (or other parameters) while camera preview is live, or while capture is under way, unless there is an explicit statement in documentation (e.g. manual focus management).

Comment: Ill stop the preview before the change, thanks!